# Codename One Gui Builder error

Tags: codenameone

New install of Eclipse Mars.1, install codename one from market place, new install of Java 1.8 running on OSX 10.9.4.

Eclipse and the project itself are set to use Java 1.8 for all compilations, I also changed the settings in the build.xml to set 1.8 as the version to use.

When I try to add a gui builder page by right clicking on the project title and selecting "New/Other" and selecting Gui Builder, then next & finish I get the error.... '<>' operator is not allowed for source level below 1.7.

Searched Google for the error and nothing related to Codename one.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: are you able to open the new project setting? (right click->CodenameOne->CodenameOne Settings)

Answer (score 1):

Open `build.xml` and do **find and replace** to replace all 1.7 with 1.8.

Open project properties (You will find it under **File**), and switch to **Sources** tab, make sure that `Source/Binary Format` is set to `JDK 8`.

Switch to **CodenameOne** tab and select `Build Hints`, now add `java.version` key and give it a value of `8`, if it's not already added.

Comment: Also make sure that Eclipse itself is running on Java 8. This is pretty hard to do especially on Mac OS where the ini file is hidden in the application bundle see: https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#-vm_value:_Mac_OS_X_Example

Comment: I'm not finding a "Sources" tab under properties. I've made the other changes including running Eclipse under 1.8.

Comment: It should be on the left tree-view links on the left pane of properties.

Comment: Not on the version I have. There is a "Java Compiler" item that is set to 1.8?

Comment: Here is a screen cap of the properties page for the project. As you can see there isn't a "Sources" tab. Am I in the wrong place? https://www.continuousbusiness.com/downloads/CN1-Properties.png

Comment: Open `build.xml` file from your project folder in notepad or similar and do find and replace from there.

Comment: I did that earlier. All the source and target fields in the build.xml file have 1.8 as the value... Did I miss something???

Comment: Any other solutions?  I am having the same problem on Eclipse Mars, running on linux.  Eclipse.ini requires 1.8, build.xml all set to 1.8, CodenameOne build hints set to 8.  Sources tab doesn't exist.

Comment: Try to set to it to 1.7. Save it and it will ask to rebuild, do it, and then reset to 1.8 and rebuild again.
It may help

Comment: kaya: by 'it' I assume you mean the setting in build.xml.  I changed that to 1.7, saved, build, changed it back to 1.8 still get the same error

Comment: We posted an Eclipse update yesterday that might resolve this issue

Comment: Nope, i mean like in the picture from EvilGenius -> under Java Compiler Settings of the Project.

Answer (score 1):

The latest plugin v 1.0.0.201606211322 resolves this issue